# How to add custom checkout step after payment and review step?

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, custom, onestepcheckout

- I want to add an additional checkout step after the payment and review step.
- if anyone knows the solution to add the custom checkout step after payment and review step then please add a solution here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have researched and found the below blog for adding step after payment step.

- https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/add-a-new-step-in-checkout-page-magento-2/

In this blog, there is a step by step description for how to add custom checkout step after payment step.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 3 step checkout extension for Magento 2 with many UI improvements.
It adds review step after shipping first step and payment second step.
https://www.3step-checkout.com/

And the programatically solution to just add a step you can find it here:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html

Comment: I want to do it using a custom module. Devdocs provide a steps to add custom steps but not after payment step so if you have any Idea please share.

Comment: The 3rd step can be added as in the documentation. No big difference. The problem is the payment step. It has the payment methods that are created dynamically in `Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/list.js`. I think you can't access them in 3rd step. You can try though. All this because you need to add a button on the 3rd step to finalize checkout. So, hide in payment step `Place Order` buttons for each payment method. And on last step trigger the jQuery click event on the current/active payment method to place order. I can't give you a full solution because it's too big and fairly complex.